# not getting the map when I get the LatLng from another api(openweathermap) that exists inside an other function

Tags: javascript

I give the initMap function arguments to call it inside the getWeather() one and have the parameters be the data from response. please help me.

````
  'use strict';

  function initMap(latt, lonn) {
    exports.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('coord'), {
      center: {
        //
        lat: latt,
        lng: lonn,
      },
      zoom: 8,
    });
  }

  exports.initMap = initMap;
})((this.window = this.window || {}));

function getWeather(unit) {
  const baseUrl = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather';
  const apiKey = 'c1324c84503b87d7b5673182adeeeb23c';
  const cityToSearch = $('#cityToSearch').val();

  $.ajax(`${baseUrl}?q=${cityToSearch}&appid=${apiKey}&units=${unit}`)
    .then(function (response) {
      initMap(`${response.coord.lat}`, `${response.coord.lon}`);```
````